# How to write python code for the below curl request to send a post request and uploading an image as binary

Tags: python, api

```
curl --request POST -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --data-binary "@/C:\\Users\\U6068366\\Downloads\\Koala.jpg"  https://c6y09pww43.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/p
```

--

```
App_Url = "https://p7a0km3l6k.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/preprod/v1/images/trademark/metadata/providerPartition/{providerPartition}/providerPartitionId/{providerPartitionId}"
    # f = open('C://Users//UX016491//PycharmProjects//DSSApi//data1.json')
    # requests_json = json.loads(f.read())
    files = {'media' : open('C:\\Users\\UX016491\\Desktop\\images\\image123.jpg','rb') }
    response = requests.request("POST", App_Url, files = files, headers={"content-type": 'application/octet-stream'})
    print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_createimage_data()
```

Comment: on http://curl.trillworks.com you can convert curl to python code

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I added url from python example because url in curl was incomplete. But it still need two values `providerPartition` and `providerPartitionId`

---

On https://curl.trillworks.com/ you can convert `curl` to python code. And mostly it works.

Here code from this page. But I can't test it.

```
import requests

# incompletet url from curl
#url = 'https://c6y09pww43.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/p'

providerPartition = '??'
providerPartitionId = '??'

url = f'https://p7a0km3l6k.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/preprod/v1/images/trademark/metadata/providerPartition/{providerPartition}/providerPartitionId/{providerPartitionId}'


headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
}

data = open('C:\\Users\\U6068366\\Downloads\\Koala.jpg', 'rb').read()

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

print(response.text)
```

You can also test both with url https://httpbin.org/post and it will send back what it get from you. And you can compare results from both requests. I tested `curl` and `python code` and I go the same information so they should give the same effect.

Comment: i tried the code .. but i m getting the below response                  <Response [415]>

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: maybe because your curl was incomplete. Now I see In python code you use different url and it has places for extra data `{providerPartition}` `{providerPartitionId}`